# Simplifying R Code: dlpylr mutate, multiplication of certain columns based on values in a separate data frame

Tags: r, multiplication, dplyr

I have been trying to do a multiplication within a mutate, using values in a different data.frame (which has only one row which contains the values), and multiply entire columns with the same column names. I managed to make it work but this was the only way I could do it, and it looks very messy. I was wondering if someone could help me simplify it. (Preferably in a way which would allow me to keep it within a larger dpylr chain).

```
prioritydata <- data[, -(3:16)] %>%
                mutate(Q1 = as.numeric(Q1) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q1),
                       Q2 = as.numeric(Q2) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q2), 
                       Q3 = as.numeric(Q3) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q3), 
                       Q4 = as.numeric(Q4) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q4), 
                       Q5 = as.numeric(Q5) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q5), 
                       Q6 = as.numeric(Q6) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q6), 
                       Q7 = as.numeric(Q7) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q7), 
                       Q8 = as.numeric(Q8) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q8),
                       Q9 = as.numeric(Q9) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q9), 
                       Q10 = as.numeric(Q10) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q10),
                       Q11 = as.numeric(Q11) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q11), 
                       Q12 = as.numeric(Q12) * as.numeric(questionweighting$Q12))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better option.  If the columns are all numeric and have the same number of rows, then subset the 'Q' columns in both datasets, multiply the equal-sized datasets and update the 'data' for those columns

```
nm1 <- paste0("Q", 1:12)
data[nm1] <- data[nm1] * questionweighting[nm1]
```

---

In `tidyverse`, this can be done with `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2_df(data, questionweighting, ~ map2_at(vars(nm1), .x
                                .y , ~
                                 as.numeric(.x) * as.numeric(.y)) %>%
                                bind_cols)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. There doesn't appear to be a function called map2_at, and this doesn't work as it is still multiplying specific columns - I want a way to multiply all columns from another data frame with this data frame.

Comment: I have just managed to do it using this: mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(.) * questionweighting$.), 3:14) but thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `data[nm1] <- map2_df(data[nm1], question_weighting, `*`)`, but didn't test the other option